# Why does Islam want everyone to be converted into their religion?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, religion

I have attended many seminars regarding the Islam to know it closely so that my some of the assumptions be cleared as much as possible. One of the e-seminar that I just watched was of Dr.Zakir. He wanted people to believe in Islam, and to get converted in to their community. Why would and person want that to be done?

Comment: your last sentence is a bit unclear!

Comment: why would he ask people who are present in the seminar to  turn Muslim? Why does a person belonging to Muslim community instead of acknowledging their religion , they try that a non Muslim person should turn Islamic.

Comment: I think one of the reasons for that is that they consider Islam is a religion for all mankind and that they want to invite people to be part of it!

Comment: that's exactly my question.. Why would anyone want, mankind to be a part of it? What if Christians from other country come there spreading Christianity, and also at the same time Christianity is been misrepresented in a very awful way.

Comment: Ok you mean Christianity is misrepresented in those seminars? Well Christians try to spread Christianity in Algeria and Morocco as far as i can tell, especially among poor people by words and financial aide ... so this is nothing new.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I doubt that Dr Zakir will do such a thing, if he does then he will have to answer to God and he definitely knows that! However spreading religion in such a way (taking advantage of financial weakness) is definitely a wrongful act!

Comment: Why anybody does or does not decide to do something is a very personal and subjective decision; if you want to know why Dr Zakir wants people to convert people, you'd probably have to ask Dr Zakir himself. Without a reasonable basis that this is actually based on Islamic belief (rather than just something that certain groups of Muslims do), it's not really answerable here. See also relevant meta discussion at http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/354/22

Answer (score 5):

My answer will not explain the actions of Dr Zakir, however, I will touch on the topic.

In Islam, it is our duties to convey and make others aware of the teachings of Islam as this is what we were commanded to do.

> “Convey (my teachings) to the people even if it were a single
>   sentence” (Sahih Bukhari, Vol.4, Hadith 667)
>
> Who is better in speech than one who calls to Allah, does righteous
>   deeds and says indeed I am among the Muslims.  Quran, Sura 41
>   (Fussilat), ayah 33
>
> “Therefore do thou give admonition, for thou art one to admonish. Thou
>   art not one to manage (men's) affairs.” (Quran 88:21-22)

As most Muslims are firmly bonded with their religion, they follow the teachings of Islam, as mentioned within the Hadeeth below, that we should love to our brothers in religion and humanity what we love to ourselves, therefore as we love our religion we wish that our brothers in humanity and faith love it too! which may be another reason why we invite others!

> On the authority of Abu Hamzah Anas bin Malik (may Allah be pleased
>   with him) - the servant of the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings
>   of Allah be upon him) - that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah
>   be upon him) said : "None of you will believe until you love for your
>   brother what you love for yourself." Related by Bukhari & Muslim

Although that we invite or give others information about our religion, this does not mean that we have to force or compel people to join or act upon the teachings of the religion, as the most important aspect is faith and only God knows whether a person has it or not!

> “Let there be no compulsion in religion: Truth stands out clear from
>   Error:” (Quran 2:256)

In regards to your comment, all Muslims are aware of the presence of other religions, we simply don't agree with the teachings and that's it, we don't have to do anything else!

> “To you is your religion, to me is mine” Quran 190

Comment: Barak Allah-u Feek, great answer my dear brother. May Allah (SWT) bless you and grant you Al-Firdaws, Ameen!

Comment: @Atata Ameen thanks, your comment brought a smile to my face, Jazak Allah kheir! same stands for you inshallah!

Comment: thank you so much brother.... :-) wish we could meet each other...and let the world know what people like you think about Islamic... It would be my pleasure if we can show the true meaning of Islamic religion and teachings of Quran is a right way.

Comment: @JIjoNair My pleasure Bro, I am based in the UK.